# How to calculate running total without using windows function

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Android SQLite version is 3.19 and doesn't support windows function like over and row_number(). I don't have any auto incremented column. I have created view using data from different table. My view details are below.

```
 1 means in stock
 2 means out stock 
 3 means reset count and start from given quantity.

 uniquekey is unique id for each row
```

I want to get running total as below:

```
  uniquekey         date        ProductName uniqueKeyProduct InOutType  quantity runningTotal 

 edfrgdctydkkc   2020-06-07    Apple          dheykdhr          1        10         10
 edfrgdctkduxc   2020-06-08    Orange         xdefrttk          1        20         20
 fdfrgdctydysc   2020-06-08    Apple          dheykdhr          2        5          5
 3dfrgrtkvctyf   2020-06-08    Apple          dheykdhr          1        2          7
 ctgrteerylkdc   2020-06-09    Orange         xdefrttk          2        8          12
 edffjritydmnc   2020-06-10    Orange         xdefrttk          3        5          5
 kkdjdjrgdctyk   2020-06-10    Apple          dheykdhr          3        2          2
 egdhgdctyjjdc   2020-06-11    Orange         xdefrttk          1        20         25
 edfryrytymnbc   2020-06-15    Apple          dheykdhr          1        10         12 
 fgeegdctydk3c   2020-06-18    Apple          dheykdhr          2        2          10
 hyidfhhhfd89c   2020-06-20    Orange         xdefrttk          2        8          17
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have any auto incremented column

Assuming that you haven't defined the table using **WITHOUT ROWID** then you still have an equivalent column, namely the **rowid** column.

- AUTOINCREMENT is an alias of the rowid column, it is inefficient and rarely required
- You may wish to read https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

> I want to get running total as below:

As the **date** column does not determine the insert order *(e.g. 2020-06-08 2 Apple rows were processed)* the **rowid** column has been utilised (not 100% failsafe in this regard).

- You may wish to consider making the date a column that holds the date and time of the insert.

One way to accomplish the above would be to utilise a **TRIGGER**. Triggers are driven by an INSERT UPDATE or DELETE event. So it makes sense to use a trigger whenever a row is inserted to then set the runningtotal.

The following TRIGGER maintains the running total for the data that you have provided.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS mytable_after_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON mytable
    BEGIN
        UPDATE mytable SET runningtotal = 
             CASE
                /* in stock */
                WHEN new.inouttype = 1 THEN 
                    COALESCE(
                        (
                        SELECT mt1.runningtotal
                        FROM mytable AS mt1
                        WHERE mt1.rowid < new.rowid AND mt1.uniquekeyproduct = new.uniquekeyproduct
                        ORDER BY rowid DESC 
                        LIMIT 1
                        ),0
                    )
                    + new.quantity
                /* out stock */ 
                WHEN new.inouttype = 2 THEN
                    COALESCE(
                        (
                            SELECT mt2.runningtotal
                            FROM mytable AS mt2
                            WHERE mt2.rowid < new.rowid AND mt2.uniquekeyproduct = new.uniquekeyproduct
                            ORDER BY rowid DESC 
                            LIMIT 1
                        ),0
                    )
                    - new.quantity
                /* reset */
                WHEN new.inouttype = 3 THEN new.quantity
            END
            WHERE rowid = new.rowid
        ;
    END
;
```

- note that the table name **mytable** will likely have to be changed. Perhaps the trigger's name should be changed as well.

The following is the SQL used to test the above. It

1. Drops the Trigger
2. Drops the Table
3. Creates the table (this may need to be amended appropriately)
4. Creates the Trigger
5. Inserts all the rows (note that the runningtotal column defaults to 0)
6. Queries the resultant table showing the runningtotal and also the rowid

:-

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytable_after_insert;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable 
    (
        uniquekey TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
        date TEXT, 
        productname TEXT, 
        uniquekeyproduct TEXT, 
        inouttype INTEGER, 
        quantity INTEGER, 
        runningtotal INTEGER DEFAULT 0
    )
;
 CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS mytable_after_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON mytable
    BEGIN
        UPDATE mytable SET runningtotal = 
             CASE
                /* in stock */
                WHEN new.inouttype = 1 THEN 
                    COALESCE(
                        (
                        SELECT mt1.runningtotal
                        FROM mytable AS mt1
                        WHERE mt1.rowid < new.rowid AND mt1.uniquekeyproduct = new.uniquekeyproduct
                        ORDER BY rowid DESC 
                        LIMIT 1
                        ),0
                    )
                    + new.quantity
                /* out stock */ 
                WHEN new.inouttype = 2 THEN
                    COALESCE(
                        (
                            SELECT mt2.runningtotal
                            FROM mytable AS mt2
                            WHERE mt2.rowid < new.rowid AND mt2.uniquekeyproduct = new.uniquekeyproduct
                            ORDER BY rowid DESC 
                            LIMIT 1
                        ),0
                    )
                    - new.quantity
                /* reset */
                WHEN new.inouttype = 3 THEN new.quantity
            END
            WHERE rowid = new.rowid
        ;
    END
;
INSERT INTO mytable (
    uniquekey,date,productname,uniquekeyproduct,inouttype,quantity /* running total not supplied so defaults to 0 */
    )
    VALUES 
        ('edfrgdctydkkc','2020-06-07','Apple','dheykdhr',1,10),
        ('edfrgdctkduxc','2020-06-08','Orange','xdefrttk',1,20),
        ('fdfrgdctydysc','2020-06-08','Apple','dheykdhr',2,5),
        ('3dfrgrtkvctyf','2020-06-08','Apple','dheykdhr',1,2),
        ('ctgrteerylkdc','2020-06-09','Orange','xdefrttk',2,8),
        ('edffjritydmnc','2020-06-10','Orange','xdefrttk',3,5),
        ('kkdjdjrgdctyk','2020-06-10','Apple','dheykdhr',3,2),
        ('egdhgdctyjjdc','2020-06-11','Orange','xdefrttk',1,20),
        ('edfryrytymnbc','2020-06-15','Apple','dheykdhr',1,10),
        ('fgeegdctydk3c','2020-06-18','Apple','dheykdhr',2,2),
        ('hyidfhhhfd89c','2020-06-20','Orange','xdefrttk',2,8)
;
SELECT rowid,* FROM mytable ORDER BY rowid ASC
```

The result being :-

[image]

- Note that if normalisation rules were followed then there should be
  another table for the products and thus that the product name would
  not be duplicated, all that would be needed was the uniquekeyproduct.

  - e.g. if a product name were changed then all rows in the mytable table would have to be updated whereas if there were a product table a name changed would be just need the 1 row to be updated and it would be reflected when querying mytable (the ProductName column would no longer be required).
- COALESCE is used to convert the null returned when the first row for a product is inserted as there are no rows that match the selection criteria for in stock and out stock actions. see https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-coalesce/
- CASE ..... END is for conditional processing of the **inouttype** column. It has 3 WHEN clauses one for each of the types (1,2 or 3). see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case
- In the subqueries used within the first two WHEN clauses tables are given a temporary name mt1 and mt2 respectively, using **AS** to ensure that there is no ambiguity as to where the data is to come from.
- Note that the as 3.19 is quite old the above was tested on more recent versions so there may be some issues. You may wish to have a look through https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html if you come across issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and awesome explanation. 
I had forgot to mention above sample is not a table .(that's why I had putted, I don't have any auto incremented column) I Have created View using data from different table.

Comment: Triggers can be applied to views using  `INSTEAD OF` see https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_triggers. The above could be used as a model. AUTO_INCREMENT is irrelevant (_unless `WITHOUT ROWID` has been used_), you can access the **rowid** column and have that as a column in the view.

Comment: @Shambhusharan P.S. https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#some_example_triggers has an example of a TRIGGER on a view.